# Using Java on FreeRTOS?

Tags: java, embedded, freertos

Can I use Java on FreeRTOS?

If so, are there any good URLs to help me get started?

What problems can I expect?

Comment: This might be a good start. http://www.freertos.org/index.html?http://www.freertos.org/Eclipse.html If you can install Eclipse, you need to have Java to run it.  I googled `FreeRTOS java` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Eclipse doesn't run on FreeRTOS but you can use it as an IDE for your C cross compiler to target FreeRTOS running on your choice of microcontroller.

Comment: I imagine you need to have a JavaME port rather than a from Java SE JVM to fit on many micro controllers.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587780/are-there-any-freertos-interpreted-language-libraries-available)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a Java VM to run Java code. I doubt very much that there is a Java VM implementation specifically designed to run on FreeRTOS, rather you would probably have to hook the VM into the underlying OS in the porting layer for your target.  Some VMs implement scheduling themselves and do not need an OS to support threading.

Consider:

- [JamaicaVm](http://www.aicas.com/jamaica.html) (Commercial & Free Personal Edition)
- [MicroJVM](http://www.is2t.com/en/products-microjvm.php) (Comercial)
- [Aonix Perc](http://www.atego.com/products/aonix-perc/) (Commercial)
- [PreonVm](http://www.virtenio.com/de/produkte/software/virtuelle-maschine.html) (Commercial)
- [AvianVM](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/) (Open source)
- [Open Mika](http://www.k-embedded-java.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=25:openmika&catid=2:products&Itemid=14) (Open source)
- [Squawk](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/squawk/index.html) (Open source)
- [SimplRJT](http://www.rtjcom.com/main.php?p=home) (Open source needs no RTOS for threading support)
- [Kaffe](http://www.kaffe.org/) (Open source).

You might also benefit from reading this [article by Michael Barr and Jason Steinhorn](http://www.netrino.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Kaffe-Java-Virtual-Machine)

Answer (score 2):

My contribution is to suggest one looks to: http://www.ajile.com

It seems that they deliver '*java on a chip*'; I'm software so I have no idea if it works.  I can say that 10 years working with applications, middle ware and operating systems 'stuff' where we fortunately had some-times had ways to access people on the chip-design teams.  (Imho) most of the time there was a Chinese wall between the 'hard ware' and 'software' cliques.  I am deliberately including "virtual machine" people in  'hardware' group.

I haven't run things on [aJile](http://www.ajile.com) silicon.  I'm just promoting a seemingly *more natural* option that could evolve into a Java Machine that works -- Somewhat similar to the BBC (and now ARM silicon), Forth, Smalltalk, or M2 that began life on an "Ideal Machines".

If I may; I have one quite significant caveat based on my hard-won lessons.  No "virtual" anything is going to make sense.  There will always be a conflict between the "virtual folk" and any "programmer mob".  That's as may be.  It will not often help Ms/Mr End-user of XYZ, Vermont, USA ...  (Or, will it?)

My personally most satisfying tasks/projects were when we engaged with any *available* (or *accessible*) the hardware (or ideal-machine / virtual-machine) in a peer-to-peer dialogue.  That doesn't seem to happen that much these days; may be we just need DSL-s instead of hardware or virtual machines??? (*irony* :flag).

~ aloha